# Google Cloud Batch + Workflow: how to connect to Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-compute-engine

I have a Workflow implemented on GCP that triggers a containerized batch job. (Here is the tutorial for something similar: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/tutorials/batch-and-workflows). The service account that runs this job has the "Cloud SQL Client" role.

Still, I keep on getting this error when trying to connect to the database (in python using psycopg2):

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/cloudsql/PROJECT_NAME:us-central1:DB_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Why?

Comment: Can you detail your batch job? Does it run a Cloud SQL proxy sidecar to open the socket?

Comment: The batch job is based on a Google Cloud Workflow with the Yaml below. The only difference is that I provide extra env variables with passwords. You will be able to see that the workflow invokes a container via http. That is all, I didn't do anything SQL-specific, as I assumed that the service account with proper permissions will be enough. Could you share instructions for sidecar implementation? Tx

Comment: ```main:
  params: [args]
 ...
    - createAndRunBatchJob:
        call: googleapis.batch.v1.projects.locations.jobs.create
        args:
            parent: ${"projects/" + projectId + "/locations/" + region}
            jobId: ${jobId}
            body:
              taskGroups:
                taskSpec:
                  runnables:
                    - container:
                        imageUri: ${imageUri}
                # Run 6 tasks on 2 VMs
                taskCount: ...
              ...```

Comment: The problem is not in Workflow, the problem is in your container. Your container required a CLoud SQL socket which is not open. You can create a subprocess in your current container, not sure you can have sidecar container with Batch. Review the container your deploy, be sure it works standalone, and then plug it in Workflow again.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan from the Cloud SQL Connector team here. There are two ways to go about this.

**First option:** Configure your application to connect to your Cloud SQL database instance using TCP and the Cloud SQL Connector for Python. [Python connector example](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors#python). This uses the `pg8000` database driver. Unfortunately, the connector does not work with the `psycopg2` library.

**Second option:** Add the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy container to your batch job.

This is a slightly modified job workflow definition from the [Run a Batch Job](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/tutorials/batch-and-workflows) guide:

Replace <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> with the connection string from your database, something like `my-project:uscentral-1:instance`

Replace <DB_PORT> with a TCP port appropriate for your database. The proxy container will start listening on this port when it starts. Your application should use it's database driver to connect to `localhost:<DB_PORT>`.

In this configuration, your application will still need to authenticate to the  database using database username and password. If you want to use IAM Authentication, you will need to adapt this based on the [Cloud SQL Proxy Guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#using-a-service-account).

````
main:
  params: [args]
  steps:
  # ... snip ...
  - createAndRunBatchJob:
      call: googleapis.batch.v1.projects.locations.jobs.create
      args:
        parent: ${"projects/" + projectId + "/locations/" + region}
        jobId: ${jobId}
        body:
          taskGroups:
            taskSpec:
              runnables:
              # The Cloud SQL Proxy container, opens a database port at
              # localhost:<DB_PORT> accessible to your application container
              - container:
                  imageUri: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.8.2
                  background: true
                  commands:
                  - "--structured-logs"
                  - "--port=<DB_PORT>"
                  - "<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>"

              # The application container, uses a standard database library to
              - container:
                  imageUri: ${imageUri}
                environment:
                  variables:
                    DB_HOST: "localhost"
                    DB_PORT: "<DB_PORT>"
            # Run 6 tasks on 2 VMs
            taskCount: 6
            parallelism: 2
          logsPolicy:
            destination: CLOUD_LOGGING
      result: createAndRunBatchJobResponse
# ...snip...```

Let me know if this works for you.
````

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan,

This didn't work for me.  Here is the yaml output from describing the job

```
  taskSpec:
    environment:
      variables:
        POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
    runnables:
    - background: true
      container:
        commands:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy
        - -instances=myproject:myregion:myinstance=tcp:5432
        - -enable_iam_login
        - -structured_logs
        imageUri: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.28.1
    - container:
        commands:
        - load_postgres
        imageUri: myimage
```

And the logs

proxy

```
message: "Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for myproject:myregion:myinstance"
Ready for new connections
```

client

```
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed
```

UPDATE:

The trick seemed to be to set

```
taskGroups:
  taskCountPerNode: 1
  taskSpec:
    runnables:
    - container:
        options: "--network=host"
```